# I am getting "exception": "instance.salesforce.com"

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to consume sales force rest api service in my application.At that time,i am getting this exception "exception": "instance.salesforce.com".

Please observe my source code

```
String orgLimitUrl           = "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/limits/"

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
HttpGet getRequest           = new HttpGet(orgLimitUrl)

getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken )
getRequest.addHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1" )

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest)

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())))

while ((orgLimitLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    orgLimisList.append(orgLimitLine)
}

httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
```

Please help me.

Thanks
Anuradha

Comment: Is that the whole error message ? It may help if you include what operation you're trying to do or share some code.

Comment: What "instance" refers in https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/limits/, is this a real endpoint?

Comment: Hi sandy,Thanks for reply.I refered one url.They gave url for each service.Please see this url "http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/".By using that url,i am consuming services in my application

Comment: Are you substituting in your instance name, like CS2, NA5, AP1, etc. . . .?

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT hard code the Salesforce instance.

Salesforce Instance is retrieved when we get access token. In response to login.salesforce.com    it provides a json containing accesstoken, instance_url etc. which looks like:

```
{
"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000jXtlEAE/00590000001LjyRAAS",
"issued_at":"1392529622903",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"instance_url":"https://eu2.salesforce.com",
"signature":"acwHCJ9BeQczNFFBIk3dV2O8O2fGzkgWq4H8z4zzuZI=",
"access_token":"00D90000000jXtl!AQYAQGaorn7i0658sX6p8v.02OiuSJTcl6GXoi3Y92V1to2DVySlLl0XljgeEgF7aIgazQ.40TeMdoh3gMYFdH4Wl5JUhOBE"
}
```

Use that **instance_url** + `/services/data/v29.0/limits/` or any other query path

Comment: Hi regal,I did according to you told.Its working fine.Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 2):

You have "https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/limits/" as your URL, but there is no such host as instance.salesforce.com, you need to substitute in your real instance name e.g. "https://na13.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/limits/" for your API request. If you login via the UI you can see what your instance is there, or if you got your access token via OAuth, the OAuth result also includes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your endpoint URL.  If there is authentication problem, you'll get login exception.  See if other integrations in your org  are working or if the same exception is thrown. You can contact salesforce support if you can't debug the problem.

Comment: yes this is only whole error message.